# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException1000

Tags: java

```
public class Employees {
    private String[] onomata,eponyma;
    private int[] kwdikoi;
    private int i,kwdikos;
    private String onoma,eponymo;
    private long kwdikoslong;

    {
        FileReader reader = null;

    try {
        reader= new FileReader("employees.json");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    JSONParser jsonparser= new JSONParser();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonobj = (JSONObject) jsonparser.parse(reader); 
        JSONArray baseArray =(JSONArray) jsonobj.get("employees");

        for (int i=0;i<baseArray.size();i++) 
        {
            JSONObject jsonobj2 = (JSONObject) baseArray.get(i);
            onoma=(String) jsonobj2.get("onoma");
            onomata[i]=onoma;
            eponymo=(String) jsonobj2.get("eponymo");
            eponyma[i]=eponymo;
            kwdikoslong=(long) jsonobj2.get("kwdikos");
            kwdikos=(int)kwdikoslong;
            kwdikoi[i]=kwdikos;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: After getting a `FileNotFoundException` do you think it is wise to continue?

Comment: Please show the stacktrace.

Comment: Also, post the employees.json file.

Comment: here is the employees.json file
{
"employees":
[
{"onoma":"Kyriakos","eponymo":"Theodoridis","kwdikos":3511},
{"onoma":"Dimitris","eponymo":"Soukos","kwdikos":3522},
{"onoma":"Tasos","eponymo":"Gkortsopoulos","kwdikos":3533},
{"onoma":"Aggelos","eponymo":"Gogos","kwdikos":3544},
{"onoma":"Giorgos","eponymo":"Mpoulari","kwdikos":3555},
{"onoma":"Aris","eponymo":"Gouri","kwdikos":3566},
{"onoma":"Giorgos","eponymo":"Georgis","kwdikos":3577},
{"onoma":"Panos","eponymo":"Vadiakas","kwdikos":3588},
{"onoma":"Aggelos","eponymo":"Babis","kwdikos":3599},
]
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You need to edit the question and put the new information there. Not in comments.

Comment: I keep getting this : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at project2.Employees.<init>(Employees.java:37)

Comment: Which line is #37?

Comment: onomata[i]=onoma;

Comment: `private String[] onomata,eponyma;` declares the variables, but they are still null.  Why not use an ArrayList instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
private String[] onomata, eponyma;
```

The variable `onomata` is never initialized.

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonobj = (JSONObject) jsonparser.parse(reader); 
    JSONArray baseArray =(JSONArray) jsonobj.get("employees");

    // initialize it here
    onomata = new String[baseArray.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i< baseArray.size(); i++) 
    {
        JSONObject jsonobj2 = (JSONObject) baseArray.get(i);
        onoma=(String) jsonobj2.get("onoma");
        onomata[i]=onoma;
        eponymo=(String) jsonobj2.get("eponymo");
        eponyma[i]=eponymo;
        kwdikoslong=(long) jsonobj2.get("kwdikos");
        kwdikos=(int)kwdikoslong;
        kwdikoi[i]=kwdikos;
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will not fix all the exceptions. As and when you encounter them, start initializing the arrays and fix them.

---

Side notes:

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514087/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nullpointerexception1000/61514360#comment108814557_61514087), you should not continue your code when a `FileNotFoundException` occurs.

It is better to do this:

```
jsonobj2.getString("onoma", "DEFAULT");
// than this: (String) jsonobj2.get("onoma")
```

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) is the generic solution to all the `NullPointerException`s.

Comment: Thank you, but what about kwdikoi, as you said this will not fix all exceptions. This worked for onomata and eponyma but the error keeps at kwdikoi now. How I can initialize this because it is integer. Sorry if i am asking something obvious but i am new!

Comment: `kwdikoi` is an integer array so it will be `kwdikoi = new int[baseArray.size()];`